# Obtain IR diffuse data from WISE

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, data-analysis, python

I need some help obtaining IR background diffuse data from the WISE observation. There is already some work done in this regard; see: http://wise.skymaps.info/ . These are .fits files. How do I find out the photon irradiance for a range (say glat b/w 0 and 30) from these files? Any help is appreciated. Also, how do I correlate this with UV flux for the same range using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have downloaded their software from the link you provided and have astropy installed, you should be able to do:

```
from wssa_utils import wssa_getval
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

# Declare your wanted point in Galactic co-ordinates
c = SkyCoord(l=0, b=30, unit=(u.deg,u.deg), frame='galactic')
ra = c.icrs.ra
dec = c.icrs.dec
vals = wssa_getval(ra, dec)
```

The results look like they will be in MegaJanskys per steradian, which would be `u.MJy/u.sr` in astropy units.
For UV data, I'm not sure what is best, maybe [GALEX](http://galex.stsci.edu/GR6/) ?